# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises

Tags: swift, dyld

I am trying to adding FBLPromises framework in app. Its working on simulator but not working on device, when i try to install it on device it 
says Build Succeeded, and gives below erro. 
[Image Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUF58.png)
Already tried restarting laptop, cleaning project.
As most of people said to add FBLPromises framework to Frameworks section, but when i tried it is doubled up.
I am using Xcode 11.3.

Answer (score 5):

try to comment this line in Podfile, help for me (Create new Project before and reinstall all)

## use_frameworks!